# How can I import a meta graph with the tensorflow c++ API?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I've found a few resources for how to import a model with Tensorflow c++ after exporting it to a `.pb` file, but my understanding is that the `.pb` file method has been replaced with a newer method which uses the `tf.Saver.save` method to produce a `.meta`, `.index`, `.data-00000-of-00001`, and a `checkpoint` file. I cannot find anything on how to import a model from these file types with the C++ API.

How can I do this?

Comment: did you get any success with this?

Comment: @Mj1992 nope, I just ended up using `.pb` files.

Comment: this tutorial was very helpful for me https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc . He used `.pb` too but i think that would be the right way to go about it.

Comment: @MatthewDrill Could you link the resources you found to import `.pb` files in the tensorflow C++ API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use TFLearn wrapper on the top of Tensorflow, but the process should be identical with plain Tensorflow models. You can save a checkpoint from TFLearn [in this way](https://github.com/kecsap/tensorflow_cpp_packaging#save-a-checkpoint-in-python-tflearn) correctly, but you can also [freeze](https://github.com/kecsap/tensorflow_cpp_packaging#freeze-a-checkpoint-snapshot-into-a-model-in-python) if you want to use a .pb model. It is possible to load both a [checkpoint](https://github.com/kecsap/tensorflow_cpp_packaging#load-a-checkpoint-in-c) or a [model](https://github.com/kecsap/tensorflow_cpp_packaging#load-a-frozen-model-in-c) file in C++. In any case, the [inference part](https://github.com/kecsap/tensorflow_cpp_packaging#inference-in-c) is identical in C++.